# How to return data from async function in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I create an app with flutter and sqflite, I want to get data from my sqflite to json, this is my code

```
getIncome() async{
    var dbClient = await db, data;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery("select * from income");

    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
      data = json.encode(list);
    }

    return data;
  }
```

when I print the result is `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'` How to solve it? thanks

Comment: `Future.then()`

Answer (score -1):

you need to call function specially, like `getIncome().then()` or `await getIncome()`, in 2019 more preferable way is to use `async/await`
you can read more at [documentation](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures)